# How can I connect Azure API Management to API Apps in the new Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

In Azure Classic, we are using Mobile Services to create our APIs.  We are using API management to call the APIs and using the Mobile Service Application Keys to connect API Management to the Mobile Services.  We have been able to port the code over to the new Api Apps, but it appears the [Application Keys have been deprecated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/#strongwarningstrong).  Is there an equivalent to these keys in the new portal to connect API Management to the API App?